# Panel resizing behaviour

Tags: wpf, layout, panel

I need a panel with 3 items arranged horizontally, one aligned left, one right and the last **centered in the remaining space**.  I can get this with:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="TextLeft" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkOrange"/>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="TextRight" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkOrange"/>
    <TextBlock Text="TextMiddle" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]

But I'd like that when the width is smaller than the sum of item widths that it is "TextRight" that gets eaten into NOT "TextMiddle" as is shown below:

[image]

Note Ive tried adding MinWidth on TextMiddle - but this **doesn't** change the behavior - because TextMiddle is last child of a LastChildFill="True" DockPanel.

The XAML below gets me the **correct behavor on resize** (TextRight gets eaten into when space in limited) **but "TextMiddle" is not centered** in the available space when there is enough width:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False" >
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="TextLeft" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkOrange"/>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="TextMiddle" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="TextRight" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkOrange"/>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]
[image]

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this - maybe by using a subpannel in one of the items - but I just cant get my head around exactly how.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is it?

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" MinWidth="350"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Rows="1">  
       <TextBlock Name="TextLeft" Text="TextLeft" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkOrange"/>  
       <TextBlock Name="TextMiddle" Text="TextMiddle" FontSize="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />  
  </UniformGrid>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="TextRight" FontSize="40" Foreground="DarkOrange"/>  
</Grid>
```

Comment: Um not quite there - that gives same behaviour as my second xaml block in question (I.e resize behaviour correct but MiddeText not centered in available space). But I think your approach is good - should be able to work this into a solution... somehow.

Comment: Persistance pays off!  With some fiddling of MinWidth that works.  Thanks alot for you effort on this - was alot more difficult than I first though (I guess thats WPF allover). :-)